# Construtor de botoes em JavaScript canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas

Estou com uma dúvida ao criar um construtor de botões para *Canvas* no JS, eu já consigo detectar o clique na área do botão, mas gostaria de simplificar o código com um construtor, para agilizar meu processo de criação do conteúdo, porém não faço ideia de como faze-lo.

Aqui um exemplo do meu código:

```
var bt = new Botao(0,0, 100, 50); // cria o botao

//construtor de botoes simples.
// eu utilizo um construtor de canvas por isso o parâmetro "canvas".
function Botao(x,y,w,h, canvas){
this.x = x;
this.y = y;
this.w = w;
this.h = h;
this.render = function(){
   canvas.context.fillRect(this.x,this.y,this.w,this.h);    
 }  
}

// aqui eu detecto o click do usuário.
function click (evt) {

var rectNav = game.canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); //obtêm as coordenadas do mouse na janela do cliente.
var pos = {
    x: evt.clientX - rectNav.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rectNav.top
 }; 

    if(pos.x>bt.x && pos.x<(bt.x+bt.w) && pos.y>bt.y && pos.y<(bt.y+bt.h)) {
    alert("click")};    // verifica se o click foi na area do botao "bt".

};
```

A minha dúvida é: como faço para colocar todo esse código da detecção do "clique" dentro do meu criador de botões, onde eu possa apenas chamar a função, por exemplo, `bt.click(codigo para ser executado)` dentro de uma função que eu atualize constantemente sem ter que criar esse código adicional, e sem ter que criar um `eventListener` para tal.

Grato!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não vejo como possas criar um event handler com a criação do botão pois o canvas não tem elementos como o SVG. O que tens de fazer é calcular onde foi clicado e ter uma array de botões que possas verificar quando houver um clique.

Algo assim:

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

//construtor de botoes simples.
// eu utilizo um construtor de canvas por isso o parâmetro "canvas".
var botoes = [];

function Botao(x, y, w, h) {
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.w = w;
  this.h = h;
  this.render = function (color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color = color || '#000';
    ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.w, this.h);
  }
  botoes.push(this); // <------------------------ inserir o botão
}

function onTarget(pos, bt) {
  return pos.x > bt.x && pos.x < (bt.x + bt.w) && pos.y > bt.y && pos.y < (bt.y + bt.h);
}

// aqui eu detecto o click do usuário.
function click(evt) {
  var rectNav = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(); //obtêm as coordenadas do mouse na janela do cliente.
  var pos = {
    x: evt.clientX - rectNav.left,
    y: evt.clientY - rectNav.top
  };

  botoes.forEach(function (btn) { // <---------- verificar os botões
    var clicado = onTarget(pos, btn);
    if (clicado) btn.render(btn.color == '#000' ? '#ccf' : '#000');
  })
};

canvas.addEventListener('click', click);

var bt = new Botao(0, 0, 100, 50).render(); // cria o botao
var bt = new Botao(30, 30, 100, 50).render(); // cria o botao
```

```html
<div>Clica-me!</div>
<canvas></canvas>
```

#### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hd8ermpf/

#### Edit:

Para usar funções diferentes em cada botão pode usar-se uma lógica de callback assim:

```
function Botao(x, y, w, h, callback) {
  this.cb = callback;
  // ... etc
```

#### jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/hd8ermpf/2/